# How can I export a raster layer as .png with a transparent background from my QGIS project via pyqgis?

Tags: python, raster, qgis, pyqgis

The goal is to programatically export a raster layer from my QGIS project as a .png with a transparent background and 0 margins around the layer.

I am able to get exactly what I want using the GUI, below are the steps I follow to get the desired result.

1. Hide all layers except for the raster layer I am wanting to export
2. Open the print layout tool
3. Add the map to the canvas
4. Set the extents of the map item to match the raster layer extents.
5. Disable the map items background
6. Set the page background color to transparent
7. Click the "Resize Layout to Contents" button after verifying all margins are set to 0 so that the page size fits the map perfectly.
8. Export as .png.

I have tried and tried with python, and have successfully exported the image, but the layer did not fit the page perfectly and I couldn't get a transparent background.

Comment: Could you add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how you export the `.png` file?